# How can I capture the Messages from msbuild in cruise control?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I have Messages in my build file but I don't see them anywhere in my logs or trace files. I'm looking at ccnet logs and msbuild logs but I dont see any. Is that a setting some where?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To **capture MSBuild messages**, you must configure a listener in CC.NET.
Add the `logger` tag in your configuration project:

```
<msbuild>
  ... your MSBuild configuration 
  <logger>C:\cc_net\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.dll</logger>
</msbuild>
```